# Purge directories seperated by yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: bash, unix

I have directory structures created every day like
/data/2018/01/01
/data/2018/01/02
.
.
/data/2018/02/01 like this.
Now I need to keep only 10 recent days and delete the rest of the locations .How can I do this with Unix shell ?

Answer (score 1):

### If you are really sure the folders getting created daily then you can use ctime:

#### You can use -print before you using the delete or exec rm -rf command to be sure everything looks OK:

```
find /data/2018 -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -ctime +10 -print
```

#### Followed by delete if everything looks OK:

```
find /data/2018 -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -ctime +10 -delete
```

#### OR by '-exec rm -rf '

```
find /data/2018 -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -ctime +10 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

#### If you prefer to delete folders with a better overview in my opinion then I want to provide another example, edit XX for how many days back you wanna delete from day 11.

```
for days in {11..XX}; do rm -rf $(date --date "$days days ago" "+%Y%m%d");done|sed 's/./&\//4'|sed 's/./&\//7'|sed 's/^/\/data\//g'
```

> Output:

```
removed directory  '/data/2018/12/14'
removed directory  '/data/2018/12/13'
removed directory  '/data/2018/12/12'
removed directory  '/data/2018/12/11'
removed directory  '/data/2018/12/10'
removed directory  '/data/2018/12/09'
removed directory  '/data/2018/12/08'
removed directory  '/data/2018/12/07'
removed directory  '/data/2018/12/06'
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
find /data -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d | sort | head -n -10 | xargs -r -d '\n' rm -rf
```

This will list all 3rd-level directories under `/data`, and sort them, earliest first, and remove the last 10 entries from the sorted list, then pass them to `rm -rf` so they're all removed.

It's recommended that you first check the output without the last part `| xargs rm -rf` before proceeding.